# External battery backup for mac mini's AC power cord

Tags: power-supply, power-bank

I have a mac mini that I am now using as a server, and I need to prevent data corruption in case of blackouts, brownouts, power cuts, etc.

I first wanted to use some battery backup PSU, but my possibilities could be limited, since it's a mac mini.

Is there anything like a battery, whose input for charge is from the socket, and it's output is a male AC power cord that fits into the mac mini, that can be used as a battery backup in case of cuts?

Comment: Have you looked at UPSs? They plug into the wall, and have multiple outlets. That way, you can plug other things into them as well, like a modem and wireless router for your internet.

Comment: @Cfinley The UPS looks reasonable. The price seems fine too. I will find a good one, and then I'll decide if that's what I'm looking for. Thanks